# How to enable libx264 in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode with libx264 in ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -i frames/%03d.bmp -vcodec libx264  out.mp4
```

However, i get the following error message:

```
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
```

If us type `ffmpeg` in the console, it shows under configuration --disable-libx264, so I guess that is the reason.

How can I enable this? I found in some other questions that it can be done by reinstalling with this option, but there where two things I could not find:

1. Is it possible to change the configuration without reinstalling?
2. If not, how do I pass options while reinstalling?

Comment: Which OS are you trying this on? Some distributions of ffmpeg don't include the x264 _encoders_ because of hollywood reasons. You can check your available codecs using the `-codecs` argument.

Comment: @MMM I am using ubuntu 20.04 within windows subsystem for linux. I think the x264 encoder is not there, but i tried to install it with `sudo apt install libx264-dev`

Comment: Where did you get this ffmpeg? The version from the repo supports libx264. Why not just use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the configuration without reinstalling?

The --disable-libx264 flag is a bit misleading. This is not an option that disables the h264 codec during installation, but is a compile flag during creation of your binary/executable. To change that flag, you either need to recompile it yourself, or install a version which had it enabled during compilation. This comes down to the repository you are downloading it from. I can confirm h264 is available on the native x64 Ubuntu version in 18.04.

> If not, how do I pass options while reinstalling?

You need to get ffmpeg from a different source which did not disable it. The native windows version installed by [chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=ffmpeg) has the flag enabled on my system. It might be that WSL uses a separate repository which disabled it.

As for how to proceed:

- Use the native windows version of ffmpeg
- Try a different Ubuntu version, e.g. 18.04 LTS
- Download ffmpeg from a different source, [example](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)
- Compile ffmpeg from [source](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem the ffmpeg binary that you have does not have the codec enabled. If you check the codecs as advised by @MMM above

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep 264
```

you should see a line

```
DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi )
```

The important part is the first 2 letters, tells you both decode and encode is supported. Either you'll need to download a binary with the library enabled or compile from scratch. The step by step instructions on the ffmepg website are easy enough to follow.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

I usually compile from scratch but only because I personally want the libfdk_aac which is licenced differently and cannot be distributed. The same restriction does not apply to x264.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the compilation guide earlier and found that i should run `sudo apt install libx264-dev` to install the x264, but this seems to be not enough.

Comment: You'd still need to compile ffmpeg with the switch --enable-libx264.  see here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu about 2/3 the way down.

However, most versions you find already compiled will have it enabled by default. It is only the non-free option for the codecs where the licence prohibits binary sharing that are generally omitted. i.e. I use MINT and their version has x264 enabled as do the windows binaries from the ffmpeg distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rpmfusion, I tried this command and it worked for me

```
sudo dnf swap ffmpeg-free ffmpeg --allowerasing
```

Source: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/Multimedia